# How to read only a subset of columns into a dataframe in julia?

Tags: julia

I have a file like this:

```
chr1    47727   47778   2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:2202:6839:64070 1   +
chr1    48132   48183   2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:2109:14612:23955    60  +
chr1    49316   49367   2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:1107:8369:30676 1   +
chr1    57049   57100   2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:1205:2852:33393 60  -
chr1    59296   59347   2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:2306:14160:96792    1   -
chr1    62116   62165   2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:1203:3949:66047 60  +
chr1    64636   64687   2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:2112:11315:75619    60  -
chr1    108831  108882  2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:2211:11748:76230    60  +
chr1    150522  150573  2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:2108:11820:88376    60  -
chr1    180744  180794  2PJ3LS1:190:C5R7BACXX:3:2115:5327:39987 60  -
```

I do not care about columns 4 and 5. Is it possible to ignore these when reading my giant file? There is nothing in CSV.read which allows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - this is not a CSV file so I would rather parse it directly (this is not maximally efficient, but in most cases it should be good enough):

```
df = DataFrame(a=String[], b=Int[], c=Int[])
for line in eachline("filename.txt")
    a, b, c = split(line)
    push!(df, (String(a), parse(Int, b), parse(Int, c))) 
end
```

EDIT: if you want also column 6 use (I assume last column is a `Char`):

```
df = DataFrame(a=String[], b=Int[], c=Int[], d=Char[])
for line in eachline("filename.txt")
    a, b, c, _, _, d = split(line)
    push!(df, (String(a), parse(Int, b), parse(Int, c)), d[1]) 
end
```

Comment: CSV.read takes a delim :) Your answer does not take into account more than three columns, right?

Comment: Yes `a`, `b` and `c` take only three first columns. The problem with your file is that each row has a different number of columns. Actually you will be able to use `CSV.read` to parse this file in the future, but there is currently a bug in `ignorerepeated` keyword argument. After it is fixed you will be able to write something like `CSV.read("filename.txt", delim=" ", ignorerepated=true, header=["a", "b", "c"])` to get what you want (but since it does not work now I did not recommend it).

Comment: Oh - actually there is the same number of columns in each line. Anyway - this does not change what I recommend.

Comment: My file is regular, 6 column tab-separated. It is just the it does not display that way :)

Comment: This is what I thought :) - simply it shows up as several spaces in SO. Anyway in this way the solution is simple - add a header to the file `"a\tb\tc"`. When you add it `CSV.read` will ignore in the output columns after third when reading in the file.

Comment: Okay, but here I want columns 1,2,3 and 6. I guess it works if you only want the first three :)

Comment: Ah - I will fix the answer then.

Comment: Additionally you can check out https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/154#issuecomment-420875884 for an approach recommended by the creator of CSV.jl.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you could use awk to create another file with only the columns you want. In Julia:

```
run(pipeline(`awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $6}' filename.txt`, "otherfile.txt"))
df = CSV.read("otherfile.txt",delim=" ")
```

I don't know if it's the most efficient, since it involves creating an intermediate file, but is quite simple and allows you to save the file if you need it later on. For removing any of them or both, just run `rm("anyfile.txt)`.